# Send Woocommerce registration confirmation email when administrator register a new Woocommerce client

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, code-snippets, wordpress-shortcode

I'm trying to create a snippet that send the woocommerce registration confirmation email to the new woocommerce clients that are registered by the administrator so they can see their password or reset it.

Here is the snippet i've made :

```php
function custom_trigger_new_customer_email($user_id) {
    if (in_array('customer', wp_get_current_user()->roles)) {
        WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_Customer_New_Account']->trigger($user_id);
    }
}
add_action('user_register', 'custom_trigger_new_customer_email', 1, 1);
```

But it does not seam to send the mail.
Have you any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fix my problem: the problem was the way i was getting the roles here is my working snippet

```php
function custom_trigger_new_customer_email($user_id) {
    if (in_array('customer', get_userdata($user_id)->roles)) {      
         $generated_password = wp_generate_password(); // Generate a random password
        
        // Set the generated password for the user
        wp_set_password($generated_password, $user_id);
        
        $mailer = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_Customer_New_Account'];
        $mailer->trigger($user_id, $generated_password, true);
    }
}
add_action('user_register', 'custom_trigger_new_customer_email', 1, 2);
```